# ¿Cómo modificar los datos de una clase la cual es parte de otra clase? (Anidacion)

Tags: c++

Tengo 3 clases distintas, una se llama fecha que contiene tres atributos, otra que se llama producto que contiene varios atributos, entre ellos uno de tipo Fecha(la clase anterior)llamado entrada y otra clase que es Inventario donde contengo un arreglo;

En el inventario guardo todos los productos, pero mi error es que cuando quiero dar un valor al atributo entrada(que es de tipo Fecha) y después mostrarlo.

Por ejemplo, en el caso de registros seria algo asi:

```
struct registro1{                         
    registro2 datos;
}                                         

struct registro2{
    int dia;
    string mes;
}
```

en este caso para modificar o imprimir datos sería algo así:

```
variable.registro1.dia 
variable.registro1.mes
```

¿En el caso de oop como sería entre clases?

----- Muchas gracias ya lo resolví, es muy parecido a la estructura solamente era suponiendo que tenia la primera clase e(producto) y la otra clase (entrada con los atributos privados dia,mes y anio), seria algo así:

producto.entrada.setDia;
producto.entrada.setMes;
prooducto.entrada.setAnio;

al igual para obtener los valores era lo mismo solo con el getter:

producto.entrada.getDia;
producto.entrada.getMes;
prooducto.entrada.getAnio;

Comment: Sería exactamente igual con clases; pero deberías hacer que los datos estén en el área `public` de la clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las clases y las estructuras son exactamente idénticas en C++ salvo por un detalle tonto:

`struct` tiene `public` como visibilidad por defecto mientras que en el caso de `class` la visibilidad es `private`. Es por eso que en el caso de `class` **siempre** vas a encontrar algún `public`. De acuerdo a este punto, los siguientes ejemplos son equivalentes:

```
struct registro1
{
  registro2 datos;
};

struct registro1
{
public:
  registro2 datos;
};

class registro1
{
public:
  registro2 datos;
};
```